# FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult return nil iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, ios11, fbsdkloginkit

With iOS 11 FBSDKLoginManager (v.4.25.0) use SFAuthenticationSession instead of SFSafariViewController, if user cancel Sign In, FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult always return nil and result.isCancelled code not work:

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logInWithReadPermissions:@[PERMISSIONS]
                               fromViewController:self
                                          handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                            if (error) {
                               //Error happen
                            }
                            else if (result.isCancelled) {
                               //User cancel
                            }
                            else {
                               //Login success
                            }
                        }];
```

In this case always happen error with description 'com.apple.SafariServices.Authentication Code=1 "(null)"'. So, in this case, we can't discern really error from SFAuthenticationSession error. Any ideas how to handle different errors? Or just need to wait FBSDK update?

Comment: the key point of the answer is using logout method of the FBSDKLoginManager before the take any action with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FBSDK version [ **4.17.0** ] with **ios 11** and it works fine

```
  let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logOut()

    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email", "user_friends"], from:self, handler:
        {


            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in


            if facebookError != nil
            {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
            }
            else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)!
            {


                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")

            }
            else
            {


            }
    })
```